# How to Left join match data in order

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is link user with last/next appointment, which order by several situation like status = 2 first, then time, confirmed and so on

Every table are very huge, so I filtered and sort them, and it looks well, however when I try to get first match data with DISTINCT it turns back to order by system and gave me wrong data.

Do you have any suggestion?

```
SELECT User.*, NextAppointment.*, LastAppointment.*                  
FROM( User )
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT( user_id ))
        FROM( SELECT Appointment.id, Appointment.user_id
              FROM( Appointment )
              WHERE Appointment.from_time>='2020-05-26'
                AND Appointment.status=1
              ORDER BY Appointment.from_time, Appointment.confirmed=1 DESC, Appointment.id DESC
            )NextAppointment_sub

        GROUP BY user_id 
    )NextAppointment    ON NextAppointment.user_id = User.id

LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT( user_id ))
        FROM( SELECT Appointment.id, Appointment.user_id
              FROM( Appointment )
              WHERE Appointment.from_time<='2020-05-26'
              ORDER BY Appointment.status=2 DESC, Appointment.from_time DESC, Appointment.confirmed=1 DESC, Appointment.status=1 DESC, Appointment.id DESC
            )LastAppointment_sub

        GROUP BY user_id 
    )LastAppointment    ON LastAppointment.user_id = User.id AND LastAppointment.from_time >= User.FirstRequest
```

Comment: Have you had a look at what `EXPLAIN` says?

Comment: Are you using a MYSQL version with window functions, like mysql-8.0+ or mariadb-10.2+?

Comment: @tadman I just have a look, there have one big temp table Using filesort, and last/next appointment are really small using where, most of them are using PRIMARY key. Are those information you expecting for?  >"<

Comment: @danblack my version is 10.2.32-MariaDB, mysqlnd 5.0.12

Comment: "Using filesort" is usually a recipe for bad times.

Comment: @tadman I think it's because it auto create temp table and sort when I using GROUP +DISTINCT to get that unique data 

so I need to think about how to get the only data without Group >"<

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query